# JMeter Regular Expression Extractor Not Working For IFrame

Tags: java, jmeter

I have web Apps.There is one JSP page that contains Iframe.
For Load testion of That JSP page i am using regular expression extractor for sending value to post URL.

In that Extractor:

```
Regular Expression is :
name="name" value="(.+?)"
```

In JSP page:

```
<body>
<iframe>
<input name="name" value="3" />
</iframe>
</body>
```

This JSP page appears after GET URL.After that GET url i have wriiten post extractor in JMETER so that i can manupulate variables and send it to post.
Please give me solution.
My problem is i am not getting values in extractor it is setting it to DEFAULT value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work for me with jMeter 2.9.

Regular expression extractor as below.

[image: See the regex definition here.]

And the result is as below.

[image: The results is here.]

Comment: There is problem if i am using JMeter 2.6?

Answer (score -1):

Use jmeter http url rewriting modifier

Worked fine in my case :)

Comment: It would be good if you could add some more explanation about your answer.